# Django - Form Save

Tags: django, tags

I can't save my signup form. I use allauth

base.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'userauth.forms.SignupForm'
```

models.py

```
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Userr(models.Model):
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Userr
        fields = ['tags']

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()

        
        user.userr.tags = self.cleaned_data['tags']
        user.userr.save()
```

i get error

AttributeError at /accounts/signup/
'User' object has no attribute 'userr'

Comment: You can't access to `userr` from `user` car in your model `Userr` there is no relation with `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Answer (score 0):

now the code does not throw an error but nothing is written in the objects "tags"

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Userr
        fields = ['tags']


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(SignupForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.extra_field = self.cleaned_data["extra_field"]

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

in wagtail admin i got : empty fields, it looks like taggit doesn't save the form to the database